# UIWebView, mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction

Tags: ios, uiwebview

i have a webview that contains a web page, the web page only contains one video and once the web page open the video inside this web page played directly!!, Is this Property ( mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction )  could helps he out??

i read the documentation but i didnt got the point..
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950

thnx

Answer (score 0):

Well mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction is set to YES by default, thus preventing any media playback without user interaction.
If you set mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction to NO, audio and video in your UIWebView can autostart in it.

Comment: KKetch,, thanx so much i got it :)